# MongoDB collection doesn't load on port

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

the program doesnt show errors but when i run it on browse all i get is 2 brackets
here is my code

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const CompteModel = require('./models/Compte.js');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/école');

app.get("/getCompte", (req, res) => {
     CompteModel.find({}, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            res.json(err);
        } else {
            res.json(result);
        }
     });
});

app.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log("Hello");
});
```

---

Here is the schema of the collection "Compte".

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const CompteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ login: { type: String, required: true, }, password: { type: String, required: true,

},
});

const CompteModel = mongoose.model("Compte",CompteSchema); module.exports = CompteModel;
```

Comment: Are you sure you have data in your collection?

Comment: yes there is data on my collection

Comment: What do you see when you console log your result?

Comment: i see the msg on the code and there's no error

Comment: make sure db is connected. `mongoose.connect(URL).then(()=>console.log("db connected")).catch((err)=>console.log(err))`

Comment: Test it with postman or thunderclient, I think you will need to use express' bodyparser feature

Comment: Please post your schema, and also the name of the collection that you want to query. This has nothing to do with `body-parser` or `json` middleware, as others are suggesting.